# Django python error: auctions.models.Listing.DoesNotExist: Listing matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, match

I am try to display a listing page. Though it displays well, django keeps giving this error as below:

> raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
> auctions.models.Listing.DoesNotExist: Listing matching query does not exist.

the index view displays all the listings by iteration, and the listing view displays a specific listing view by receiving a variable as "form.title".

my code is as follows:

views.py:

```
def listing_view(request, title):

# if get a listing page
categories = Category.objects.all()

# Get all the forms submitted
forms = Listing.objects.all()

# get the highest bid for a listing
highest_price = Bid.objects.filter(title=title).order_by("-bid_price").first()

# Get the listing with the title

listing = Listing.objects.get(title=title)

if highest_price is not None:
    listing.current_price = highest_price.bid_price

# else set starting price as the current price
else:
    listing.current_price = listing.starting_price
    listing.save()
```

index.html:

```
<!-- image of a listing -->
<div class="col-4">

  <a href="{% url 'listing_view' form.title %}">
    {% if form.image %}
    <img src="{{ form.image.url }}" alt="" width="267px" />
    {% elif form.image_url %}
    <img src="{{ form.image_url }}" alt="" width="267px" />
    {% endif %}
  </a>
</div>
```

listing.html:

```
<!-- image in the left of the container -->
    <div class="col-4">
        {% if listing.image %}
        <img src="{{ listing.image.url }}" alt="" width="267px" />
        {% elif listing.image_url %}
        <img src="{{ listing.image_url }}" alt="" width="267px" />
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

the html file here is to clarify that the variable "listing" is needed in the listing page display, because it says does not exist, so I tried to use try and except instead of statement, but it gives me another error as below:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'listing' referenced before assignment

I understand that I made it a local variable, so return render couldn't reach it.

But how can I get the listing object without the errors?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a Bid with some title, then a Listing with the same title. Is that logic correct?

Comment: Yes, it's like a ebay product listing, each Listing and Bid object has some fields defining the listing and bid each user created or made. I am trying to display an index page with listings and specific listing page with user logged (with more functions) in or not.

Comment: I think it is the url path: `re_path(r"^(?P<title>[^/]+)$", views.listing_view, name="listing_view")` it had an additional "/" before the "$" sign. After deleting it, it seems fine now. I will further test the whole application later.

Answer (score -1):

There could be errors which are related to more things, Make sure you have made the MIGRATION and MIGRATED your Listing model via

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If that is done correctly then make sure that in your returning value of the view listing_view passes in the context something like this

```
return render(request, 'yourdir/index.html)
```